# Reading and writing in UTF8 a text file in C using regex

Tags: c, regex, unicode, utf-8

I have to write a simple piece of code that acts on a file; my software have to scans the file searching for a pattern with a regex (I never had to use the regex in C, but generally speaking, I know them) and it always have to pretends to decode and encode in UTF8.

The file has also a UNIX file format and it could be really nice to have multiple regex running at the same time like with an OR statement or similar.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do this in C?

Comment: @Arkku What do you have to offer? :D I'd like to use the C but also Java can be a good alternative to me

Comment: Well, you didn't specify what else the program should do except scan for regexp matches, but something along the lines of Ruby, Python, perhaps even Perl come to mind. Or just `grep` if that's all you want. You could even run any of these from within the C program and read the output of the more regexp-friendly program.

Comment: @Arkku ok, considering all this modern languages, which one support UTF8 ? My problem also involve the unicode encoding charset, i need the regex but i do not want to messed up the file.

Comment: @Micro Perl has very good Unicode and regex support. In fact, there is nothing else out there that comes close. You have to do a few declarations at the top to make dealing with encoded streams easier, but beyond that, it's super user friendly.

Comment: @tchrist can you provide some examples?

Comment: @micro: There are lots of Unicode-processing Perl programs [here](http://training.perl.com/scripts/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the `pcre` library for using regex in C/C++. Originally because we were porting perl code to C, and its a good simple library with UTF-8 support. http://www.pcre.org/

And when we have to deal with non UTF-8 encodings we use the `iconv` library to convert to UTF-8 first. http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/